# Summarising giving same value for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

using code to get mean petal length for each specie

```
group_sp<-group_by(iris,iris$Species)
mean_plength<-summarise(group_sp,mean(iris$Petal.Length))
mean_plength
```

getting output

```
`iris$Species` `mean(iris$Petal.Length)`
          <fctr>                     <dbl>
1         setosa                     3.758
2     versicolor                     3.758
3      virginica                     3.758
```

same for all which is not the case it should be rather

```
setosa  1.464
versicolor  4.26
virginica   5.552
```

this is happening for all of my datasets can anyone tell whats the problem

Comment: You need `dplyr::summarise(group_sp, Mean = mean(Petal.Length))`  You are getting the mean of entire column by extracting from the 'iris$`  Also, in your `group_by`, it just need `group_by(iris, Species)`

Comment: Base R solution  `aggregate(iris$Petal.Length, list(iris$Species), mean)`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you don't quote column names or refer to columns with the usual subsetting/selection syntax (i.e. `$`, `[`, or `[[`). Instead the first argument is always the data, and additional arguments make reference to columns as if they were regular variables.

So the correct syntax for your example would be:

```
library("dplyr")
group_sp <- group_by(iris, Species)
mean_plength <- summarise(group_sp, mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length))
mean_plength
```

What happened in your case is that you referred to the `$Species` and `$Petal.Length` columns in the global environment, not in the environment created by the relevant function call.

Note also that the more idiomatic way to write this code would be:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length))
```

This is exactly equivalent to the following, because [the magrittr pipe `%>%`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) is forward function application:

```
summarize(group_by(iris, Species), mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length))
```